# EWS address mail in php

Tags: php, exchangewebservices, php-ews

I am using EWS PHP , how to get the email of sender?
I tried this but I got no response.

```
$item->Organizer->Mailbox->MailAdresse
```

Comment: What output does `var_dump($item);` give?

Comment: An array with values, but without the mail sender , only user name, so i want to get the mail adresse... how to do

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's just a typo, but I think it should be (based on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/aa565036(v=exchg.150).aspx)):

```
$item->Organizer->Mailbox->EmailAddress
```